# The memory could not be read

Tags: c#-3.0

I am trying to access a remote file through my application. But maximum of times whenever i am trying to access it,It shows the following error: *The instruction at "0x38d78063" referenced memory at "0xe0001ff6".The memory could not be read.*
After this it provides the option of *OK* or *Cancel*.

Can anyone put some light on this issue.

Regards,

Neil

Comment: What are you using to try and access it? File, FileStream?